# Duda con super() en python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Tengo una duda en cuanto a `super()` en `python3`, Mi duda es:

¿Cual es la diferencia entre utilizar el `super()` del ejemplo A y B?

Ejemplo A:

```
super().method()
```

Ejemplo B:

```
super(class, self).method()
```

---

***De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!***

Comment: Hola Julio, ninguna. En Python 3.x la clase y la instancia se pasan automáticamente. Pasarlas de forma explícita solo es necesario en Python 2.x o en Python 3.x si quieres que el código sea compatible con Python 2.x.

Comment: Ok, gracias!!!!